# SQL trying to rename an item

Tags: sql

In my Visual Studio application I am using 2 different SQL Functions. Both functions have first name fields so my application can't tell the two apart. I also cannot change the name of firstName in the database, so I would like to rename firstName to firstName2 in my second function like this: `(Select firstName FROM datatable2) AS firstName2`. It is giving me an error:  "single-row subquery returns more than one row."

How can I rename firstName in the function?

Comment: Have you tried anything, which you can share? Difficult to understand.

Comment: Show the whole query, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood what you want:

```
Select firstname AS firstname2 FROM datatable2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FUNCTION GetID     (p_id_no  IN  datatable2.ID_NO%TYPE)        
 RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS id_1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
 BEGIN
  OPEN id_1 FOR
  SELECT id_no,
  (Select first_name AS first_name2 FROM datatable2),
  last_name
  FROM datatable2
  Where id_no = p_id_no;
 RETURN id_1;
 END GetID;
```

This gives me a single-row subquery returns more that one row error.

Comment: replace `(Select first_name AS first_name2 FROM datatable2` with `first_name AS first_name2`

Comment: That worked thank you user16484. I know it was a stupid question but that's how I learn!